# What are the detail reasons for every SSLException

Tags: sslexception

the questions are:
(1) How many exception reasons that SSL Exception has?
(2) Are there any specifications or documents for SSL Exception?

We all know that SSL Exception has many types, such as SSLException, SSLHandshakeException, SSLKeyException,SSLPeerUnverifiedException,SSLProtocolException, etc.
for one of them, there are many exception reasons, below are some of them that I searched from internet:
(1) SSLException
    1)  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.

```
2)  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate Caused by:
    java.security.cert.CertificateException:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.

3)  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.

4)  javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException:
        the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

5)  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Invalid padding
```

(2) SSLHandshakeException
    1)  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate

```
2)  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Untrusted Server Certificate Chain

3)  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

4)  java.net.SocketException: Default SSL context init failed: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

5)  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
        sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
            sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
                unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```